# Microsoft graph: ICalUid is returned null when loading selected fields in calendarView

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

We are using the [CalendarView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint to get the list of meetings from the calendar.

If we specify $select to get limited fields the iCalUid is returned null, even though we specify iCalUid in $select.

Following is the sample request that returns null iCalUid

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime=2020-04-09T04:00:00.000Z&endDateTime=2020-05-01T04:00:00.000Z&$top=100&$orderby=start/dateTime%20asc&$select=id,subject,iCalUId
```

If we do the same call without $select filter it works fine and returns proper iCalUid.

This problem only happens with one particular tenant the above scenario is working fine for hundreds of other tenants.

Following are some details to debug the session

```
client-request-id: 9faa4f1a-4cbc-4467-8e1c-15ac34e6a2ae

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36

Request time: 1 April 2020
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried repro the issue with the above Graph API request, but it works for me. I can get the iCalUid.

You can give a try with Microsoft Graph Explorer/POSTMAN for the given tenant and see if you can still repro the issue or also you can limit the smaller number of items. If you can repro the issue, i would suggest you to check these items using tools like MFCMAPI/EWSEditor or use Microsoft CalCheck utility to see they're in good shape and fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned its even working fine over 300 customers of us, its an issue with one particular tenant only. I am expecting an answer from the MS Graph team here.

Comment: This happens to me as well. It is related to Exchange running in Hybrid mode